# post using request-promise module in node.js and getting http_outgoing.js:618 throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument', error

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, post, request

sending the body in the form way and get the data back in a json way, and getting this error any idea would be appreciated thank you 
_http_outgoing.js:618
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:618:11)
    at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:586:15)
    at Request.write (C:\Users\DomKim\Desktop\workspaceForNode\node_modules\request\request.js:1500:27)
    at end (C:\Users\DomKim\Desktop\workspaceForNode\node_modules\request\request.js:549:18)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\DomKim\Desktop\workspaceForNode\node_modules\request\request.js:578:7)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'

and this is my code

```
async  function getConnection(url,param) {
 var queryStr = generateQueryString(param)
 var result ;
  console.log(queryStr);
  let OPTIONS = {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      uri: url,
      method: 'POST',
      body:{
        queryStr
      },

  };await  request(OPTIONS).then(function(body){


           result = body;
          console.log('result in rquest.post : '+result);

   }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('error! : ' + err);
   });
   console.log('result out rquest.post : '+result);
   return result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the type of `queryStr`. It should be `String` or `Buffer`.

Comment: i console logged it and i get this i and  i think this is a string type id:testing,secret:XRRpYIoMtaJC8hFLfUN7Bw==,nameId:tomato

Comment: Let's try `console.log(typeof queryStr)` to print the type of `queryStr`.

Comment: thank you so much, solved it. the problem was in queryStr